# Chaincode has been installed, approved, committed, but still not able to invoke

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am using Hyperledger Fabric v2.2.3, in Oracle Linux 8.4
I am running without docker.
I have successfully installed, approved, committed the chaincode to my channel (orderer-channel).
I am using `peer lifecycle chaincode xxx` commands for the install, approve, and commit.
However, when I am using `peer chaincode list` command, but it list as empty.

Here are the commands and its debugging outputs.

```
[user@hyperledgerfabric ~]# /appl/hyperledger-fabric/bin/peer lifecycle chaincode install --peerAddresses localhost:7051 -o localhost:7050 \
                                                                                          /appl/chaincode/TestHLF/TestHLF.tar.gz

2021-09-06 16:07:07.506 +08 [cli.lifecycle.chaincode] submitInstallProposal -> INFO 001 Installed remotely: response:<status:200 payload:"\nHTestHLF:7544dc9a9c60359520cc16c4f2bbf0091c79a9aa7476e21c1a4cc76bd2f7e27b\022\007TestHLF" >
2021-09-06 16:07:07.506 +08 [cli.lifecycle.chaincode] submitInstallProposal -> INFO 002 Chaincode code package identifier: TestHLF:7544dc9a9c60359520cc16c4f2bbf0091c79a9aa7476e21c1a4cc76bd2f7e27b



[user@hyperledgerfabric ~]# /appl/hyperledger-fabric/bin/peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -C orderer-channel \
                                                                                                  -n TestHLF \
                                                                                                  -v 1.0.0 \
                                                                                                  --sequence 1 \
                                                                                                  --package-id "TestHLF:7544dc9a9c60359520cc16c4f2bbf0091c79a9aa7476e21c1a4cc76bd2f7e27b" \
                                                                                                  --peerAddresses localhost:7051 -o localhost:7050

2021-09-06 16:07:07.614 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 023 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000453a40, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:07.614 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 024 Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2021-09-06 16:07:07.614 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 025 Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:07.614 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 026 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000453a40, {READY <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:07.614 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 027 Channel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:07.615 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 028 parsed scheme: ""
2021-09-06 16:07:07.615 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 029 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-09-06 16:07:07.615 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 02a ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{localhost:7051  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:07.615 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 02b ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-09-06 16:07:07.615 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 02c Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
2021-09-06 16:07:07.615 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 02d Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2021-09-06 16:07:07.615 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 02e Subchannel picks a new address "localhost:7051" to connect
2021-09-06 16:07:07.616 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 02f pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0004acb80, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:07.616 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 030 Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2021-09-06 16:07:07.616 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 031 Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:07.616 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 032 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0004acb80, {READY <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:07.616 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 033 Channel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:07.617 +08 [grpc] WithKeepaliveParams -> DEBU 034 Adjusting keepalive ping interval to minimum period of 10s
2021-09-06 16:07:07.617 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 035 parsed scheme: ""
2021-09-06 16:07:07.617 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 036 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-09-06 16:07:07.617 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 037 ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{localhost:7050  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:07.617 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 038 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-09-06 16:07:07.617 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 039 Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
2021-09-06 16:07:07.617 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 03a Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2021-09-06 16:07:07.617 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 03b Subchannel picks a new address "localhost:7050" to connect
2021-09-06 16:07:07.618 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000021820, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:07.618 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 03d Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2021-09-06 16:07:07.618 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 03e Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:07.618 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 03f pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000021820, {READY <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:07.618 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 040 Channel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:07.619 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 041 Sign: plaintext: 0ADD080A7308031A0C08AB98D7890610...31613463633736626432663765323762
2021-09-06 16:07:07.619 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 042 Sign: digest: 2866DE7D44974B662CDEECFCA0C958E5884AE0FAA0C1F7E30A72A990FC65D241
2021-09-06 16:07:07.627 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 043 Sign: plaintext: 0ADD080A7308031A0C08AB98D7890610...3A0291CE38FD5CAF0782D4A75B2CB833
2021-09-06 16:07:07.627 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 044 Sign: digest: 2F0106AC9B01865833250CE5D44AC0C8EC4B75A17409E808CB1D7A391F8DEF5C
2021-09-06 16:07:07.627 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 045 Sign: plaintext: 0A85080A1B08051A0608AB98D7890622...00120D1A0B08FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF01
2021-09-06 16:07:07.627 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 046 Sign: digest: 47CF4E1203F1D14CC1AEEB7AC0776DA2F360EE23FEA927E9F5A1E66878BEB027
2021-09-06 16:07:09.652 +08 [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 047 txid [2349c7438eae022d2453d0c57b9ad44250a9aca7ce5f5647b68877b51c20dd73] committed with status (VALID) at localhost:7051




[user@hyperledgerfabric ~]# /appl/hyperledger-fabric/bin/peer lifecycle chaincode commit -C orderer-channel \
                                                                                         -n TestHLF \
                                                                                         -v 1.0.0 \
                                                                                         --sequence 1 \
                                                                                         --peerAddresses localhost:7051 -o localhost:7050

2021-09-06 16:07:09.691 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 023 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00036e440, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:09.692 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 024 Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2021-09-06 16:07:09.694 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 025 Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:09.694 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 026 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00036e440, {READY <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:09.694 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 027 Channel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:09.695 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 028 parsed scheme: ""
2021-09-06 16:07:09.695 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 029 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-09-06 16:07:09.695 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 02a ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{localhost:7051  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:09.695 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 02b ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-09-06 16:07:09.695 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 02c Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
2021-09-06 16:07:09.695 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 02d Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2021-09-06 16:07:09.695 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 02e Subchannel picks a new address "localhost:7051" to connect
2021-09-06 16:07:09.696 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 02f pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0004eb3e0, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:09.696 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 030 Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2021-09-06 16:07:09.696 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 031 Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:09.696 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 032 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0004eb3e0, {READY <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:09.697 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 033 Channel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:09.697 +08 [grpc] WithKeepaliveParams -> DEBU 034 Adjusting keepalive ping interval to minimum period of 10s
2021-09-06 16:07:09.697 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 035 parsed scheme: ""
2021-09-06 16:07:09.697 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 036 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2021-09-06 16:07:09.697 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 037 ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{localhost:7050  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:09.697 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 038 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2021-09-06 16:07:09.697 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 039 Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
2021-09-06 16:07:09.698 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 03a Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2021-09-06 16:07:09.698 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 03b Subchannel picks a new address "localhost:7050" to connect
2021-09-06 16:07:09.698 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0005c5ec0, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:09.698 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 03d Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2021-09-06 16:07:09.698 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 03e Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:09.698 +08 [grpc] UpdateSubConnState -> DEBU 03f pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0005c5ec0, {READY <nil>}
2021-09-06 16:07:09.698 +08 [grpc] Infof -> DEBU 040 Channel Connectivity change to READY
2021-09-06 16:07:09.698 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 041 Sign: plaintext: 0ADD080A7308031A0C08AD98D7890610...120754657374484C461A05312E302E30
2021-09-06 16:07:09.698 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 042 Sign: digest: 5E875D07A47E27DA338662AACC2860D9419371EDA2D57677D85149C8B18908E1
2021-09-06 16:07:09.704 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 043 Sign: plaintext: 0ADD080A7308031A0C08AD98D7890610...BD169FAD1ECF8613FFD9C8CE30A6C9AC
2021-09-06 16:07:09.704 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 044 Sign: digest: 4E45786A0763C875B6B18A7E30D2332BC45543DCA7885B39DAFC2C86F296856F
2021-09-06 16:07:09.705 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 045 Sign: plaintext: 0A85080A1B08051A0608AD98D7890622...00120D1A0B08FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF01
2021-09-06 16:07:09.705 +08 [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 046 Sign: digest: 76501C0D734448AB048D31B2DC6A8428EE8BEA6F18FD1450ED0B9058890678C9
2021-09-06 16:07:11.728 +08 [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> INFO 047 txid [7d7e22e6e7d71ebb3b73fd797114da6c0ffbf3de1ab3e0e12d4c8ac8e409fdec] committed with status (VALID) at localhost:7051
```

Here are the command I used to check the existence, and found that using `peer chaincode list` has nothing installed.

```
[user@hyperledgerfabric ~]# /appl/hyperledger-fabric/bin/peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled --peerAddresses localhost:7051 -o localhost:7051

Installed chaincodes on peer:
Package ID: TestHLF:7544dc9a9c60359520cc16c4f2bbf0091c79a9aa7476e21c1a4cc76bd2f7e27b, Label: TestHLF




[user@hyperledgerfabric ~]# /appl/hyperledger-fabric/bin/peer lifecycle chaincode queryapproved -C orderer-channel \
                                                                                                -n TestHLF \
                                                                                                --peerAddresses localhost:7051 -o localhost:7051

Approved chaincode definition for chaincode 'TestHLF' on channel 'orderer-channel':
sequence: 1, version: 1.0.0, init-required: false, package-id: TestHLF:7544dc9a9c60359520cc16c4f2bbf0091c79a9aa7476e21c1a4cc76bd2f7e27b, endorsement plugin: escc, validation plugin: vscc




[user@hyperledgerfabric ~]# /appl/hyperledger-fabric/bin/peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted -C orderer-channel \
                                                                                                 -n TestHLF \
                                                                                                 --peerAddresses localhost:7051 -o localhost:7051

Committed chaincode definition for chaincode 'TestHLF' on channel 'orderer-channel':
Version: 1.0.0, Sequence: 1, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc, Approvals: [MyOrg1: true]




[user@hyperledgerfabric ~]# /appl/hyperledger-fabric/bin/peer chaincode list --installed \
                                                                             -C orderer-channel \
                                                                             --peerAddresses localhost:7051 -o localhost:7050

Get installed chaincodes on peer:
```

Here are the output when I execute `peer chaincode invoke`,
This one on the console during my invoke via cli:

```
[user@hyperledgerfabric ~]# /appl/hyperledger-fabric/bin/peer chaincode invoke -C orderer-channel -n TestHLF --peerAddresses localhost:7051 -o localhost:7050 -c '{"Args":["retrieve", "key1"]}'

2021-09-06 17:14:36.991 +08 [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> DEBU 043 ESCC invoke result: response:<status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 16e55029175cd3e14d8155afb932e3fbf2dabdce73db120486968fa9126af2ef: could not launch chaincode TestHLF:7544dc9a9c60359520cc16c4f2bbf0091c79a9aa7476e21c1a4cc76bd2f7e27b: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0" >
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 16e55029175cd3e14d8155afb932e3fbf2dabdce73db120486968fa9126af2ef: could not launch chaincode TestHLF:7544dc9a9c60359520cc16c4f2bbf0091c79a9aa7476e21c1a4cc76bd2f7e27b: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0"
```

Here is the peer debug log during my invoke `peer chaincode invoke` via the cli:

```
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: 2021-09-06 17:14:36.986 +08 [chaincode] Start -> DEBU 1667 start container: TestHLF:7544dc9a9c60359520cc16c4f2bbf0091c79a9aa7476e21c1a4cc76bd2f7e27b
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: 2021-09-06 17:14:36.990 +08 [chaincode] Launch -> DEBU 1668 stopping due to error while launching: container exited with 0
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:118
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: runtime.goexit
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: chaincode registration failed
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: 2021-09-06 17:14:36.990 +08 [chaincode] Launch -> DEBU 1669 launch complete
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: 2021-09-06 17:14:36.990 +08 [chaincode] Deregister -> DEBU 166a deregister handler: TestHLF:7544dc9a9c60359520cc16c4f2bbf0091c79a9aa7476e21c1a4cc76bd2f7e27b
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: 2021-09-06 17:14:36.991 +08 [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 166b finished chaincode: TestHLF duration: 4ms channel=orderer-channel txID=16e55029
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: 2021-09-06 17:14:36.991 +08 [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 166c failed to invoke chaincode TestHLF, error: container exited with 0
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:118
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: runtime.goexit
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: chaincode registration failed
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: could not launch chaincode TestHLF:7544dc9a9c60359520cc16c4f2bbf0091c79a9aa7476e21c1a4cc76bd2f7e27b
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Launch
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:85
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Invoke
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:197
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:155
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:126
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:119
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:187
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposalSuccessfullyOrError
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:398
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:340
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:32
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer/peer.pb.go:107
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node.unaryGrpcLimiter.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node/grpc_limiters.go:51
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging/server.go:92
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics/interceptor.go:31
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer/peer.pb.go:109
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1082
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1405
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:746
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: runtime.goexit
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: failed to execute transaction 16e55029175cd3e14d8155afb932e3fbf2dabdce73db120486968fa9126af2ef
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.processChaincodeExecutionResult
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:161
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:156
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:126
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:119
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:187
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposalSuccessfullyOrError
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:398
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:340
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:32
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer/peer.pb.go:107
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node.unaryGrpcLimiter.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node/grpc_limiters.go:51
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging/server.go:92
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics/interceptor.go:31
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer/peer.pb.go:109
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1082
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1405
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:746
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: runtime.goexit
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]:         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374 channel=orderer-channel txID=16e55029
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: 2021-09-06 17:14:36.991 +08 [lockbasedtxmgr] Done -> DEBU 166d Done with transaction simulation / query execution [16e55029175cd3e14d8155afb932e3fbf2dabdce73db120486968fa9126af2ef]
Sep 06 17:14:36 hyperledgerfabric peer[1570]: 2021-09-06 17:14:36.991 +08 [endorser] ProcessProposal -> WARN 166e Failed to invoke chaincode channel=orderer-channel chaincode=TestHLF error="error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 16e55029175cd3e14d8155afb932e3fbf2dabdce73db120486968fa9126af2ef: could not launch chaincode TestHLF:7544dc9a9c60359520cc16c4f2bbf0091c79a9aa7476e21c1a4cc76bd2f7e27b: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you can run Fabric components directly outside of Docker, by default the Peer will attempt to use the Docker Daemon to create an image to run the chaincode in. That's the standard way the peer works.

For more information on how to run the Fabric components directly - I'd strongly recommended looking at the [`test-network-nano-bash`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network-nano-bash)
Recently added to the samples, this shows exactly how to start all the components directly.  Though this still requires Docker for chaincode.

In terms of the chaincode and running that without docker, that is also possible using the external builders and chaincode-as-a-server features of Fabric (I'd like to get it added to that test-network-nano-bash when I get some time). Rather than installing the actual chaincode 'code', you install a package that contains a pointer to where the chaincode is running. So long as the chaincode is running at that host/port that it can be run ok.  For more information on the feature there's an [example repo](https://github.com/hyperledgendary/contract-as-a-service) - though that is about running in K8S.

EDIT:

If you want to monitor all running containers and also monitor any container that comes into being even if it dies [this script](https://gist.github.com/mbwhite/a32abc57a0a45ecc466977ceef67df1f) can be very helpful

Comment: I have another question based on your answer above, I understand that if uses external builders and chaincode-as-a-server do not required the actual chaincode to be sit on the peer, and the chaincode can be hosted at the "chaincode-as-a-server" side.
My question: is the actual chaincode that hosted at "chaincode-as-a-server" side need to be running in docker ?

Answer (score 0):

`peer chaincode list` response is empty because your chaincode as an external service is not registered by the [LSCC](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/smartcontract/smartcontract.html#system-chaincode), but you can trust `peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled`, the chaincode seems to be installed.

Your post title says you are not able to invoke. What are your problems when invoking?

Comment: because it is not listed under `peer chaincode list`, in that case, how can I invoke the chaincode via command line `peer chaincode invoke` ?

Comment: I usually use higher level tools for these kind of things, but a regular `peer chaincode invoke` should work. From https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/chaincode_lifecycle.html#deploying-a-chaincode: "You will not be able to use the old lifecycle to install, instantiate, or update a chaincode on channels with V2_0 capabilities enabled. However, you can still invoke chaincode installed using the previous lifecycle model after you enable V2_0 capabilities.".

Comment: I have updated with the debugging output and errors from my invoke. Many thanks for your help !

Comment: For any reason, although the chaincode seems to be deployed, when invoking, the peer is trying to deploy the chaincode in the old way (via docker). I cannot find the deployment error in a quick view. Maybe something related to your `connection.json`. You can compare with this guide from "Installing the External Chaincode": https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-implement-hyperledger-fabric-external-chaincodes-within-a-kubernetes-cluster-fd01d7544523. Ignore all related to Kubernetes and TLS, as your network seems to be much simpler.